# Identity rows between two matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix, row, identity

Let say we have two matrices, i.e. `M1` and `M2`, of dimensions `n1 x m` and `n2 x m`, respectively.

How we can find which rows of `M1` are identity to those of `M2` (and exceptional vice versa) ?

The preferable output is a matrix, whose the number of rows is equal to the identity rows between the matrices `M1` and `M2`, and two columns, that is, the first column will contain the number of row of matrix `M1` and the second one the number of row of matrix `M2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a slicker way, but this seems to work...

```
#dummy data
M1 <- matrix(1:8,ncol=2)
M2 <- matrix(c(1,3,4,5,6,8),ncol=2)

M1
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    5
[2,]    2    6
[3,]    3    7
[4,]    4    8

M2
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    5
[2,]    3    6
[3,]    4    8

which(apply(M2, 1, function(v) 
           apply(M1, 1, function(w) sum(abs(w-v))))==0,
      arr.ind = TRUE)

     row col
[1,]   1   1
[2,]   4   3
```

The `row` column is the row index of M1, the `col` column is the index of matching rows in M2.

Answer (score 1):

Create example matrices with 4 matching rows

```
set.seed(0)
M1 <- matrix(runif(100), 10)
M2 <- rbind(M1[sample(10, 4),], matrix(runif(60), 6))
```

Create output

```
splits <- lapply(list(M1, M2), function(x) split(x, row(x)))
out <- cbind(M1 = seq(nrow(M1)), M2 = do.call(match, splits))
out[!is.na(out[,2]),]
#      M1 M2
# [1,]  2  4
# [2,]  3  3
# [3,]  6  2
# [4,]  7  1
```